# Powershell - Reading multiple json files in a directory and output the data

Tags: json, powershell

I'm having to whip up a process that will read multiple json files created by another process.

I have code that can read a single file, but we're needing to process these results in bulk.

Here's my current code:

```
$json = Get-ChildItem $filePath -recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt [DateTime] $filesNewerThan } | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.delegates | foreach-Object {
    foreach ($File in $_.files) 
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LastName = $_.lastName
            ZipCode = $File.zipCode
            BirthDate = $File.birthdate
            Address = $File.Address}
    }
  }
```

Right now I'm getting an error about an "invalid JSON primitive" which what I'm guessing is an issue where I don't have "Get-Content" specified in my code.

Wondering what my issue is with my code.

Answer (score 0):

`ConvertFrom-Json` currently (as of PowerShell 7.0) doesn't support file-*path* input, only file-*content* input (the actual JSON string), which means that you need to involve `Get-Content`:

```
$json = Get-ChildItem -File $filePath -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt [DateTime] $filesNewerThan } |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $_.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json }
```